# Python comma delimiting a text file

Tags: python

I am learning python at the moment and I have a text file with lots of numbers separated by a newline (\n) like:

5
100
7
83

What's the easiest way to read/write into a new text file putting the numbers into a comma delimited format like:

5, 100, 7, 83

Comment: what are the documents you refereed? What you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each line in the file, you want to split it apart on spaces and rejoin it with commas:

```
with open('infile.txt') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(', '.join(infile.read().split('\n')) + '\n')
```

You could also look at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module, if you want to do anything more complicated.

Comment: In Python2.7 or Python3, you can combine the two "withs". `with open('infile.txt'), open('outfile.txt', 'w') as infile, outfile:`

Comment: I'd forgotten that. Thanks, gnibbler.

Comment: Is there anyway to split by regular expression?  The numbers are separated by a newline, so there's one number on each line (stackoverflow isn't letting me show the newline)

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for that. (You almost never need regular expressions.) Edited for splitting on newlines instead of spaces.

Comment: @gnibbler: Using 2.7 I couldn't get your code combining the with statements running. I have to use `with open(in_f, 'r') as i, open(out_f,'w') as o:`. Is your example only valid in python 3?

Answer (score 4):

Look at [the csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), which is designed for reading and writing such formats.

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest way, especially if the file is not very big

```
with open('infile.txt') as infile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.read().replace(" ", ", "))
```

csv module is overkill if you are just dealing with numbers that don't need special treatment or escaping

If the file is too large to read into memory at once, use something like Abe's answer